# Git status and distant repository

Tags: git, repository, git-status

I have some git repositories and when I do `git status` I don't have the same message

For a first repository I have (sorry in French)

```
Sur la branche master
Votre branche est à jour avec 'origin/master'.
rien à valider, la copie de travail est propre
```

And for another one I have

```
Sur la branche master
rien à valider, la copie de travail est propre
```

So I thought it was because the distant repository weren't up-to-date but it is. (difference 1)

And more strange for the second I have this behavior:

```
git commit -am "Commit message"
git status
Sur la branche master
rien à valider, la copie de travail est propre
git push origin master
git status
Sur la branche master
rien à valider, la copie de travail est propre
```

So, no difference with or without the `git push origin master`. (difference 2)

Some questions ? 
Is the difference (2) normal ?

How to know if the distant repository is up-to-date ?

I think that the difference (1) is because I didn't create them in the same way : the first one was clone and I use the command `git remote add origin url` for the second. Am I right ?
Is it better to clone or to add ?

Comment: You need to track the remote branch after adding a remote.  Try `git branch --set-upstream master  origin/master`

Comment: Super it works. I just want to add : I had the message `the option --set-upstream is obsolete and it's better to use --track or --set-upstream-to` (translate from French)